# Error in Integrated Weblogic 12C in SOA Suite - Derby server start and stop immediately

Tags: oracle, weblogic, soa, suite

I need help to solve this problem:

I've already installed Oracle SOA Suite 12c using the developer pack (from oracle official downloads). 
When I try to start integrated weblogic server (in Jdeveloper menu Run) it starts and shows listening on the port but immediately stops with following error:

```
Could: Not find or load main class
Stopping Derby Server
Derby Server Stopped
```

My config:

- Windows 2003 server Enterprise edition x64
- Jre 7
- Jdk 1.7 x64
- Oracle soa suite 12c

Comment: You may want to take a look at your `<domain>/bin/startWebLogic.cmd` and  `<domain>/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd` files. You can comment out all of the Derby parts and see if it starts up. We removed every reference to Derby from our scripts

Comment: I've tried comment out all of the Derby parts, but same error. The exception is raised in start weblogic by java command (jdk\bin).

Comment: I've redirect wls log to file and the result is : Error: Could not find or load main class and

Comment: I think the references to stopping Derby are simply the startWebLogic script tidying up after failing to start the server.  There should be a line in the logs immediately preceded by "Starting WLS with line:" showing the java command that is about to be run ending in the class to be invoked which should be weblogic.Server.  If it is then I would suspect something classpath related.  The classpath being used is displayed a little earlier in the log file.

Comment: I agree Jeremy ... the derby stop just because startweblogic fails .. so in the script after weblogic fails derby is terminated... that is right ... i'm sure the fails is in the line "java -JAVA_PARAMETERS" line, wich start weblogic... how i can discovered wich parameter fails ? any suggestion ? thanks

Comment: Have you got any more details on the error?  The log output following `Starting WLS with line:` would be useful as would the definition of CLASSPATH from 10-15 lines earlier.  Note: I tried manually blanking CLASSPATH just before invoking java and this gives `Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Server
Stopping Derby server...` - with no exception or stack trace.

Comment: Good call Jeremy, could be something like a bad value for the `WL_HOME` so the classpath isn't set up at all.

Comment: Great Jeremy ... i think this is the way ... wich value i must set up my WL_HOME ? My installation is in "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home" .. i didn't have set up environment variable called WL_HOME ... thanks !!!

Comment: You shouldn't have to set WL_HOME prior to calling startWeblogic - that script calls setDomainEnv which sets it.  This does mean that you can't just move a domain or a WebLogic installation about without fixing a bunch of scripts!  For reference, my WL_HOME gets set to D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver.

Comment: Jeremy ... Thanks a lot for help. I've checked this config and its fine ... but the same error persist .... I've downloaded an ova file from Oracle Site (instead SOA 12c this contains SOA 11g)... but its is enough for my self study. I will use this ... One more time .. thanks a lot for helper ...

Comment: No problem  - glad you've got something running at least.

Comment: Strongly suggest you *not* use Integrated WLS server for SOA as it stops whenever you shut down Jdeveloper. Suggest using Standalone domain instead: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#SOAQS251 - easy to set up and stays up even JDev is shutdown.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks again ... VM 100% working.

Comment: @Joe Thank you !!! I will see this new issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same error at home, but not in my office, both Windows environments.

What happened is that at home I have a **SPACE** in the user name, like, "John Doe".

What I did was run a small PowerShell script to change all occurrences in all *.cmd files on the Weblogic domain **bin** by the Windows 8.3 notation.

Here is the Powershell script:

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.cmd -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Firstname Secondname", "FIRSTN~1" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

You can get the location of your Weblogic local domain instance by looking in the console of Oracle JDeveloper 12c.

My Weblogic domain is at

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\DefaultDomain
```